# Get Information from RemoveDuplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a short list of values in column **K**.  If I use the Ribbon commands to remove duplicates, Excel removes the duplicates and outputs a message giving the number of duplicates removed:

[image]

If I use VBA to do the same thing:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Columns("K:K").Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

The duplicates are removed, but the message never appears.

How do I get the message to appear if I use the macro ??

Comment: Can you use countA before and after to get the information?

Comment: @ScottCraner  Good suggestion..............I'll try it.

Comment: Here's the dumbest way to do it: `SendKeys ("%+AM~"), True: SendKeys ("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}~"), True`

Comment: @J.Fox  Your suggestion works!....just had to select the column first.

Comment: Whoops yeah I should have mentioned that :) obviously using `SendKeys` is not Best Practice™ but it should work if you're on the clock until the `CountA` method pans out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MsgBox` doesn't allow a lot of room for customization, but setting up a UserForm to look exactly like the Remove Duplicates dialogue would be something you'd have to do on your end, so `MsgBox` will have to do.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RemoveDuplicatesWithReport()
Dim unique() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Long, uidCt As Long, dCol As Long, remCt As Long

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'turn off screenupdating/calculation
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'current sheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'column K
dCol = 11

'resize array for counting uniques
ReDim unique(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, dCol).End(xlUp).Row)

'count how many unique values there are (uidCt)
For x = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, dCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If CountIfArray(ws.Cells(x, dCol), unique()) = 0 Then
        unique(uidCt) = ws.Cells(x, dCol).Text
        uidCt = uidCt + 1
    End If
Next x

'count before removal
remCt = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Columns(dCol)) - 1

'remove duplicates
ws.Columns(dCol).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

'count after removal
remCt = remCt - (WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Columns(dCol)) - 1)

'turn screenupdating/calculation back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
ws.Calculate

'display results
MsgBox remCt & " duplicate values were found and removed." & vbCr & uidCt & " unique values remain.", vbInformation, "Remove Duplicates"

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description
Exit Sub

End Sub

Public Function CountIfArray(lookup_value, lookup_array)
CountIfArray = Application.Count(Application.Match(lookup_value, lookup_array, 0))
End Function
```